# Checking if the same text is appearing under 2 different xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have 2 xpaths as - `//xpath1/text()` and `//xpath2/text()` I want to form a single xpath conditional expression which will verify if the text is same for both.

Is that possible? I am ok to tweak the xpaths.

EDIT

```
..
    <test id="1">
        <testcase attr1="xyz">Jane</partyId>
        <testcase attr2="abc">Doe</partyId>
    </test>

    <test id="2">
        <testcase attr1="xyz">Jane</partyId>
        <testcase attr2="abc">Does</partyId>
    </test>
..
```

I want to verify if the text under `//test[@id="1"]/testcase[@attr1="xyz"]` and `//test[@id="2"]/testcase[@attr1="xyz"]` is same.

Comment: you want output a bool value?

Comment: Could you provide with more explicit example?

Comment: I have added a sample now, hope that clears the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

XPATH:

```
//actors[string(.)=string(//foo:singers)]
```

OUT:

```
NO MATCH!
```

**ATTATION:**

The `string()` function converts a node-set to a string by returning the string value of the first node in the node-set, which in some instances may yield unexpected results.

If you want the `string()` function to concatenate all child text, you must then pass a single node instead of a node-set.

[string Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133(v=vs.110).aspx)